# mysql select with priority of 3 filelds in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

my table and fields are like these:

[image]

i must find `$sy<year<$ey` then it must filter only values by  `$sm<month<$em` at last it must find `$sd<day<$ed`

i need to find records between dates for example like 2010/10/25 , 2010/10/10

at first i tried :

```
SELECT SUM(barname) allin,SUM(rooz) allhoghogh,user_id FROM work_result 
WHERE (`year`>='$sy' and `month`>='$sm' and `day`>='$sd') and (`year`<='$ey' and `month`<='$em' and `day`<='$ed') group by user_id ;
```

but it cant find records for dates like e like 2010/10/25 , 2010/10/28

than i tried

```
SELECT * FROM work_result as t1 join work_result as t2 on t1.year<='$sy' and t2.year>='$ey' and t1.month<='$em' and t2.month>='$sm' and t1.day<='$ed' and t2.day>='$sd' WHERE 1 group by t1.wrid
```

this isnt usful in my case!

i need some thing like priority select first select all between years than month and than day!!

other way is convert mysql records to timestamp by year and month and day and compare it by input date but UNIX_TIMESTAMP('year-month-day 00:00:00') dont worked correct for me.
i used it like :

```
SELECT * FROM `work_result` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP('year-month-day 00:00:00')>1238921453
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If convert to timestamp didn't work for you what about use `date_format` to convert:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `work_result` 
 WHERE date_format(concat(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d') > 
         DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`yourDateGoesHere`), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: my yourDateGoesHere is a timestamp number!!